# Is createreadstream asynchronous?

Tags: node.js

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options . 
I also have a general question .

Can I assume that unless otherwise stated in the documentation , any function mentioned is asynchronous?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Is createreadstream asynchronous?

Yes and no.  This question is really more a matter of semantics than anything because it hides an asynchronous operation under a synchronous looking interface.  `fs.createReadStream()` appears to have a synchronous interface.  It does not return a promise or accept a callback to communicate back when it's done or to send back some results.  So, it appears synchronous from the interface.  And, we know from using it that there's nothing you have to wait for in order to start using the stream.  So, you use it as if it was a synchronous interface.

Here's the signature for `fs.createReadStream()`:

```
fs.createReadStream(path[, options])
```

And, in the options object, there is no callback option and no mention of a returned promise.  This is not a typical asynchronous interface.

---

On the other hand if you look at the signature of `fs.rename()`:

```
fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, callback)
```

You see that it takes a callback that is referred to in the doc as the "completion callback".  This function is clearly asynchronous.

---

But, `fs.createReadStream()` does open a file and it opens that file asynchronously without blocking.

If you're wondering how `fs.createReadStream()` can be synchronous when it has to open a file asynchronously, that's because `fs.createReadStream()` has not yet opened the file when it returns.

In normal use of the stream, you can just start reading from the stream immediately.  But, internally to the stream, if the file is not yet opened, it will wait until the file is done being opened before actually attempting to read from it.  So, the process of opening the file is being hidden from the user of the stream (which is generally a good thing).

If you wanted to know when the file as actually done being opened, there is an `open` event on the stream.  And, if there's an error opening the file, there will be an `error` event on the stream.  So, if you want to get technical, you can say that `fs.readStream()` actually is an asynchronous operation and completion of the async operation is communicated via the `open` or `error` events.

```
let rstream = fs.createReadStream("temp.txt");
rstream.on('open', (fd) => {
    // file opened now
});
rstream.on('error', (err) => {
    // error on the stream
});
```

But, in normal usage of `fs.createReadStream()`, the programmer does not have to monitor the file open event because it is hidden from the user and handled automatically when the stream is read from next.  When you create a read stream and immediately ask to read from it (which is an asynchronous interface), internally the stream object waits for the file to finish opening, then reads some bytes form it, waits for the file read to finish and then notifies completion of the read operation.  So, they just combine the file open completion with the first read, saving the programmer an extra step of waiting for the file open to finish before issuing their first read operation.

So, technically `fs.createReadStream()` is an asynchronous operation that has completion events.  But, because of the way it's been combined with reading from the file, you don't generally have to use it like it's asynchronous because it's asynchronous behavior is combined with the async reading from the file.

Comment: When is the file actually opened in `createReadStream`?  You mention "sometime later", but when is that done?

Comment: @jmq - If you look in [the source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L1678) you can see that `fs.createReadStream()` creates a `ReadStream` object which calls `this.open()` in the constructor.  But, that is asynchronous so it completes sometime after `fs.createReadStream()` returns.  Other methods on the stream check to see if the file has finished being opened and if not, they register an event handler to be notified when the open finishes and they do their work after the open finishes.  This can work since everything is async.

Comment: @jmq - If you want to know when the `open` finishes, you can register an event listener for the `open` event on the stream yourself.

Comment: Rewrote this answer to be significantly more technically accurate and to elaborate on how it actually works under the covers.

Comment: `child_process.spawn` and `child_process.fork` take a parameters `stdio:[]` of length 3, corresponding to stdin, stdout, and stderr for the child process.  Possible values for any of the 3 include a a stream, but if the stream is not yet `open` (i.e., the `open` event has been generated)  an error will be thrown.  So in that case, it is not hidden from the user.

Comment: @CraigHicks - Yes, that would be a special case where you're not allowed to pass a stream object until it has a file descriptor.  That's more about the child_process implementation (because they're going to duplicate the `fd` than it is about streams in general).  But, you are correct about that one specific case.

Answer (score 1):

according to nodejs source code:

1. fs.createReadStream create a ReadStream instance.
2. ReadStream's _read method (*we know every custom readablestream must provide its _read method*) calls fs.read
3. we know that fs.read is async (fs.readSync is sync)