# Store file data in variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I am trying to save the content of a file to a variable using a stream. However, the scope of the variable is not accesible from outside the function.

```
var data = '';
var fileContent = '';
var reader = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
reader.setEncoding('UTF8');

reader.on('data', function(chunk) {
   data += chunk;
});

reader.on('end', function() {
   fileContent = data;
});

return fileContent;
```

I tried to return the value inside the function but it is not returning the expected thing.

Comment: I think you return the fileConsent variable before the stream ends, so it returns an empty string. Try to use synchronous methods from fs instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is createreadstream asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386768/is-createreadstream-asynchronous)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do want to do ist reading the file synchronously. `fs` has special mothods for this. For example [`readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options). What you try to do is reading it as a stream, but the object which you are returning immeadialty is still empty when you do this. It will eentually populated later, when the stream is processed.

So go for `sync` methods or write your code for streams or asnyc processing.