# Problem with concatenation of String in NodeJS: the data sent in the response is empty

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

This code is to append the data and send it to the client. But the data is not getting appended. Please help

```js
app.post('/api/display', (req,res) => {
   let data = "";
   const bod = req.body;
   var input = fs.createReadStream('sample.txt');

   var r1 = require('readline').createInterface({
      input: input
   });

   r1.on('line', function(line) {
      var ar = line.split("=");
      var valuetypestring = ar[0].split(" ");
      var valuetype = valuetypestring[0];
      var valuestring = ar[1].split(" ");
      var value = valuestring[1];
      for(var attributename in bod){
         if(valuetype==attributename){
            //console.log is giving the output
            console.log(`${valuetype}:${value} new value:${bod[attributename]}`); 
            //The data doesnt get appended
            data+=`${valuetype}:${value} new value:${bod[attributename]}`; 
         }
      }    
   });
   res.send(data); //Here the string is sent empty
});
```

Comment: If you put a `console.log` just before `res.send(data)` - you might see this is firing before `data` is being appended to, and still equals `""` - because `fs.createReadStream` is asynchronous:

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386768/is-createreadstream-asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

Readline, like many other modules, is **asynchronous**. That means that it doesn't block the execution of your code while waiting for data. So, you started listening for a line, but didn't wait for the data to finish sending in order to call `res.send(data)`. What you want to do is change the line:

```js
res.send(data);
```

to

```js
r1.on("close", function() {
    res.send(data);
});
```

so you know that the data has been received. Then, when you're typing in data from the console, you can press `Ctrl+D` to signify that all lines have been sent. If you're only looking to receive one line, then you don't need to wait for the `close` event, you can just move the `res.send(data)` into the line handler.